# Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content (Google Drive, iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a CSV-file to Google Drive with [files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert). Unfortunately, i got 2 issues. Please, help me to resolve it.

My project info:

- Language: Objective-C
- Pod: GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive

1/ I can't find `files.insert` in framework. So, i use `files.create`. Am i right?

2/

> Accepted Media MIME types: */*

It work fine when i use mimeType: 'text/csv'. But it look like this:

[image: CSV-file in google Drive with 'text/csv']

And, I need something like this to ensure customer requirements and ease of editing

[image: CSV-file in google Drive with 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet']

So, i change mimeType to 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'. That make me an error:

```
An error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=400 "(Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content.)" UserInfo={error=Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content., GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x7fc77c808840: {message:"Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content." errors:[1] code:400}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content.)}
```

Here is my code:

```
GTLRDrive_File *metadata = [GTLRDrive_File object];
metadata.name = @"export.csv";
NSString *content = @"a,b,c\nx,y,z";
NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"];

GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:metadata
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLRDrive_File *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
}];
```

this code SOMETIME work with my google account and GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate work so well!

```
File GTLRDrive_File 0x7fee0587b970: {mimeType:"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" id:"..." kind:"drive#file" name:"export.csv"}
```

Comment: Sorry, my language skills are limited

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to set the "source" mime type in the upload parameters, and set the "target" mime type in the File object:

```
NSData *data = [csv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *mimeType = @"text/csv";
NSString *convertToMimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet";


GTLRDrive_File *newFile = [GTLRDrive_File object];
newFile.name = fileName;
if (convertToMimeType != nil) newFile.mimeType = convertToMimeType;
if (parentItem != nil) newFile.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObject: parentItem.identifier];
GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData: data MIMEType: mimeType];
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject: newFile uploadParameters: uploadParameters];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found answers to my questions.

In this situation, i should call GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate with uploadParameters is nil to create "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet".

```
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:metadata uploadParameters:nil];
```

After that, i will call GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate with identifier of file and upload new data to my new file.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)createCSVFileWithRealm {
GTLRDrive_File *metadata = [GTLRDrive_File object];
metadata.name = @"export.csv";
metadata.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet";

GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:metadata
                                                               uploadParameters:nil];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLRDrive_File *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Save id and call upload data
    }
}];
```

}

```
- (void)uploadData {
GTLRDrive_File *metadata = [GTLRDrive_File object];

NSString *content = @"a,b,c\nx,y,z";
NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"];
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate queryWithObject:metadata
                                                             fileId:exportFile.identifier
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLRDrive_File *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

}